# Google Maps - Depois de fazer nova pesquisa, remover marker old

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Segue o código:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
        debugger
        var markers = [];
        var latitude = parseFloat('@Model.Latitude'); // -23.4811396
        var longitude = parseFloat('@Model.Longitude'); // -46.3676736
        var myLatLng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-edit'), {
            center: { lat: latitude , lng: longitude },
            zoom: 11,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker_old = new google.maps.Marker({   // <-----marcador antigo
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: '@Model.GoogleMaps_Address'
        });
        markers.push(marker_old);

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input-edit');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { types: ['address'] });
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            debugger
            markers = [];   //<------ limpar marcador antigo
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                $('#pac-input-create').val('');
                Alert("Endereço inválido");
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                  (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
            }

            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

Quando fazer nova pesquisa, ele não está removendo marker antigo. Alguma solução ?
Segue o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bronca é que estás armazenando os marcadores na variável local `var markers = [];` dentro do `initAutocomplete()`.

Nesse caso eu indico tu criar essa variável global pra não perder a referência dos marcadores.

```
var markers = [];
initAutocomplete() {
// teu código
addListener('place_changed', function () {
            markers = [];   //<------ limpar marcador antigo
```

No mais o código tá ok, isso deve limpar corretamente o mapa.